# How to hide an image on mobile in a wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I am using the [OceanWP](https://oceanwp.org/) free WordPress theme, and I've run into an issue with the header on mobile devices. The image I've used on for the header looks good on desktops, but it gets obscured by text on mobile and tablet devices. I've decided the best coarse of action is to hide the image entirely on anything not desktop.

I've tried to add this code-snippet in the stylesheet on line 2621:

```
#site-header {
background-image: none;
}
```

The snippet is placed within an @media statement:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
[...]
}
```

I've also added it in the minified version, but the image is still showing.

Can anyone see what I did wrong? Or have a different work-around that might work?

Comment: Maybe the theme style is still overriding your media query. Have you tried inspecting it with the your browser debugger or adding "!important"? If you post the link i would be happy to take a look.

Comment: Post your link.

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated, as I've only recently started to actually edit code in WordPress: http://christoffersendesign.dk/

Comment: There is no styling in your header to hide it for 959px and under. Just a max-width that seems to come from your theme. Are you sure your stylsheet is being loaded? BTW: I'm assuming it's the header with your photo in it?

Comment: My bad, I deleted it because it didn't seem to do anything. It should be back now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.min.css, go to that media query and add `!important` to your background-image tag.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
 #site-header {
  background-image: none !important;
 }
}
```

Also, while developing the website, try not to minify your css & js. Do that once all is done so it makes it much easier to code and tweak things around.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much. What does the !important do? For future reference.

Comment: @MadsChristoffersen Glad it has helped. `!important` makes that particular code higher specificity. Basically, when you have other rules that are saying that particular element must be , for example, 50px in width, if you set a width rule and `!important` to it , it will overwrite that. Usually, you try not to use `!important` and create classes and styles accordingly, but sometimes when it comes to WordPress themes, you are better off giving it `!important` than change and tweak a million classes that affects 1 particular element.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme style is overriding your own css file. Try changing the order in which your CSS is loaded or add !important after background-image:none. Like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    #site-header {
        background-image: none !important;
    }
}
```

By the way, it seems like you are not using a child theme. You might want to do that if you want to keep all your changes later on when the main theme gets updated. Take a look at [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I will. I definitely will do that! :D